# How do I animate a UIView along a circular path?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, cgaffinetransform

In Swift code, how can I start and animate a `UIView` so that it moves in a motion along a circular path, then bring it to an end gracefully? Is it possible to achieve this using a `CGAffineTransform` animation?

I have prepared a GIF below showing the type of animation I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Updated: Update code to Swift 5.6**

Use `UIBezierPath` and `CAKeyFrameAnimation`.

Here is the code:

```swift
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center, radius: 20, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi*2, clockwise: true)

let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
animation.path = circlePath.cgPath
animation.duration = 1
animation.repeatCount = .infinity

let squareView = UIView()
// whatever the value of origin for squareView will not affect the animation
squareView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
squareView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
view.addSubview(squareView)
// you can also pass any unique string value for key
squareView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

// circleLayer is only used to show the circle animation path
let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
view.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Moreover, you can set the `anchorPoint` property of `squareView.layer` to make the view not animate anchored in it's center. The default value of `anchorPoint` is (0.5, 0.5) which means the center point.

Comment: @CokileCeoi Is there anything that needs to be done to actually start the animation? I've implemented the exact same code as above except for substituting my own image and path, but no animation occurs... I can see the path and the UIImage, but the UIImage remains static and doesn't move for me...

Comment: @Justin Did you use the code in `viewDidLoad()` method?

Comment: @CokileCeoi Nope, I have separate functions for each stage. Creating the UIImageView, creating the BezierPath (and showing it with a CALayer), and creating the keyframe animation then adding it to the UIImageView. This chain of events is started (in the order listed) by the conclusion of another animation function (not in ViewDidLoad()...

Comment: Oh nevermind, I got it!! I knew that it would be totally trivial too haha. I didn't realize that in `let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")`, the (keyPath: "position") is actually referencing a needed property... I thought you could name the key path string anything you wanted haha :P Works now!

Comment: i am adding CAKeyframeAnimation in viewDidLoad() but i want to start animation after clicking a button.

Comment: @krishankumar You can move calling `add(_:forKey:)` method to your button click callback.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158323/cakeyframeanimation-not-linear-for-values-greater-than-pi