# How to animate view on circular path with iOS 10 UIViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: ios, animation, ios10

Is it possible to animate a view in a circular path using the new iOS 10 UIViewPropertyAnimator?

I know that it can be done with CAKeyframeAnimation as per [How do I animate a UIView along a circular path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416742/how-do-i-animate-a-uiview-along-a-circular-path)

How can I achieve the same result with the new API?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following. Essentially, calculating the points on circle and using animateKeyFrames to move between them.

```
let radius = CGFloat(100.0)
let center = CGPoint(x: 150.0, y: 150.0)
let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 3.0
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: animationDuration, curve: .linear)
animator.addAnimations {
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0, options: [.calculationModeLinear], animations: {
        let points = 1000
        let slice = 2 * CGFloat.pi / CGFloat(points)

        for i in 0..<points {
            let angle = slice * CGFloat(i)
            let x = center.x + radius * CGFloat(sin(angle))
            let y = center.y + radius * CGFloat(cos(angle))

            let duration = 1.0/Double(points)
            let startTime = duration * Double(i)
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: startTime, relativeDuration: duration) {
                ninja.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            }
        }
    })
}
animator.startAnimation()
```