# CAKeyFrameAnimation not Linear for values greater than PI

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I am having some trouble to understand why an animation isn't working like expected.
What I am doing is this:

1. Create a `UIBezierPath` with an arc to move a Label along this path and animate the paths stroke.

   ```
   //Start Point is -.pi /2 to let the Arc start at the top.
   //self.progress = Value between 0.0 and 1.0
   let path : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.width * 0.5, y: self.bounds.height * 0.5), 
   radius: self.bounds.width * 0.5, startAngle: -.pi / 2, endAngle: (2 * self.progress * .pi) - (.pi / 2), clockwise: true)
   return path
   ```
2. Add this path to a `CAShapeLayer`

   ```
   circlePathLayer.frame = bounds
   circlePathLayer.path = self.path.cgPath
   circlePathLayer.strokeStart = 0
   circlePathLayer.strokeEnd = 1
   ```
3. Animate the strokeEnd property with a `CABasicAnimation`

   ```
   let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
   animation.repeatCount = HUGE
   animation.fromValue = 0.0
   animation.toValue = 1.0
   animation.duration = self.animationDuration
   animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
   animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
   ```
4. Animate the position property of my label with a `CAKeyFrameAnimation`

   ```
   let animationScore = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
   //some things I tried to fix
   //animationScore.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750)]
   //animationScore.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
   animationScore.path = self.path.cgPath
   animationScore.duration = self.animationDuration
   animationScore.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
   animationScore.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
   animationScore.repeatCount = HUGE
   ```
5. Add my animations to layer and label

   ```
   self.circlePathLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
   self.scoreLabel.layer.add(animationScore, forKey: nil)
   ```

**My Problem:** For ProgressValues greater than 0.75 my label is not moving in linear speed. Values greater than 0.75 mean that my arc is greater than PI. 
For values less than 0.75 my animation works fine and label and strokeend have the same speed and are on top of each other.

GIF : 
     [image: Gif showing the animation]

Please ignore the 100% in the Label in this gif my progress was at a value of 0.76.

You see my Label slows down after three quarters of my circle.

I hope someone can help me.
Many thanks

Comment: Will you send the demo ? If you dont mind ? I will check it and return to you with solution

Comment: I don't see you setting the `calculationMode`. But in any case... Why are you using a keyframe animation at all? Just rotate the label round the circle center as an anchor point, like a planet. Think of a clock hand (remember clocks with hands?). You will need a second rotation round the label center to keep it upright, of course.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. @matt setting the `calculationMode` did not change a thing. But rotating my label around an anchorPoint seems worth trying. How would I do that? Is it just a `CABasicAnimation transform.rotation`? And i would need to create a `CAAnimationGroup` to combine both animations, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyframe animation introduces an unnecessary complication. Simply rotate the label around the center with the same duration as the shape layer's stroke animation:

[image]

(I apologize that my animation starts at the bottom, not the top, but I wasn't looking at your question when I wrote the code and now I'm too lazy to change it!)

So, how is that done? It's three animations, all with the same duration:

- The shape layer's `strokeEnd`, like your animation.
- An "arm" running thru the center of the circle, with the label as a sublayer at one end (so that the label appears at the radius of the circle). The arm does a rotation transform animation.
- The label does a rotation transform animation in the opposite direction. If it didn't, it would rotate along with its superlayer. (Think of how a Ferris wheel works; your chair is on the end of the arm, but it remains upright with respect to the earth.)

This is the entire animation code:

```
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    anim.fromValue = 0
    anim.toValue = 5
    anim.duration = 10
    self.arm.layer.add(anim, forKey:nil)

    let anim2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    anim2.fromValue = 0
    anim2.toValue = -5
    anim2.duration = 10
    self.lab.layer.add(anim2, forKey:nil)

    let anim3 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    anim3.fromValue = 0
    anim3.toValue = 1
    anim3.duration = 10
    self.shape.add(anim3, forKey:nil)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for providing this beautiful answer and explanation. Love the ferris wheel analogy btw. Just one question: I do understand the purpose of the "arm" but I'm having some trouble figuring out how i would implement something like that. Could you explain a little further please? Marking this as accepted answer.

Comment: The "arm" is just a view or layer. You can't see it because I gave it a clear background. Its purpose is merely to move the label in an orbit around the center while allowing the label to pivot on its own center to stay upright (like a Ferris wheel, as I said). Think of the arm as a "spoke" of the wheel.

Comment: Okay, I think i got the idea. Thanks again for the quick response. You helped me a lot! Btw: Do you have any idea why following a path with a keyFrameAnimation does not work as intended?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really answer your question, which was _why_ the keyframe animation adds an extra complication. I think it has something to do with the fact that the arc path is made of control points and they are regarded as dictating the "key frames" of the animation. Unfortunately we don't know where the control points are, but I think they are at the start, quarter, half, three-quarters, and end. Thus we do the first three stages (to three-quarters) in the same time, and the tiny remaining bit in the same time _again_.

Comment: That is why I commented at the outset that I didn't see you setting the `calculationMode` — it seemed to me that a `calculationMode` of `kCAAnimationPaced` would have given you a linear speed throughout the animation. But you seemed to imply you had tried that.

Comment: One of comments gave me the key: kCAAnimationPaced. Giving this option cleared my issue like the question.